# Wildcard usage in Jetty's ConstraintMapping class

Tags: jersey, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have REST endpoint method with path parameter:

```
@Path("/{id}/post")
```

Can I use ConstraintMapping to restrict access to it? Which wildcards shoul be used in *pathSpec* method?

Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 0):

ConstraintMapping follow the servlet spec rules for url-patterns.

So you have ...

- Prefix Based `/foo/*`
- File Extension Based `*.do`
- Exact declaration `/foo/bar`
- Root declaration `/`

With that particular pattern you have really 2 choices

- Prefix Based to include everything `/*`
- Exact declarations `/foo/post` + `/bar/post` etc ... for all of your `{id}`s

Comment: _ConstraintMapping follow the servlet spec rules for url-patterns._
Ok, thanks!